# Liquibase is trying to execute executed scripts

Tags: spring, spring-boot, database-migration, liquibase

we need rename changelog files which are already executed by liquibase to use relative path of master file.

When we changed filesnames in master change log
from this

```
<include file="src/main/resources/db/changelogs/changelog-1.26.xml"/>`
```

to

```
<include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="db/changelogs/changelog-1.26.xml"/>
```

From this change Liquibase always trying to execute same scripts which were executed in past.

Can you tell me how to solve this? We really need change this path to be able execute scripts from test scope.

Answer (score 1):

Without specifics, it's nearly impossible to give valid advice. However, Liquibase creates an entry in the change log table in your database for each 'change' that it executes. It computes a checksum for each of these comprised of values which are pertinent to each change. If you ever modify any of your changes, the computed checksum will no longer be the same, and won't match the one stored in your database, and Liquibase will then try and execute the 'updated' change. If you can get away NOT making changes to your prior liquibase changesets, I'd recommend that approach. However, if you must make changes, you may be able to use specify [preconditions](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html) that would prevent the sort of errors you're describing.

Comment: What specifics do you mean? We have executed scripts, and now we need location of these scripts without repeated execution of executed scripts.

Comment: The [Liquibase documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/update.html) discusses this. It says "Each change set has an 'id' and 'author' attribute which, along with the directory and file name of the the change log file, uniquely identifies it."

Based on this, it seems clear that by renaming or moving the change log files you are effectively changing the ID of every change, and therefore Liquibase considers these new changes.

Comment: I know, because of that I write here to find some solution, how to update checksum of executed files or set liqiubase to ignore filename or something like that.

Comment: Have you tried using preconditions as I suggested? I'm not aware of any way to alter how the checksums are computed.

Comment: Yes, but I can't imagine how to use it in my case

Comment: Please read the documentation link I posted. It describes preconditions like tableExists, columnExists, etc.. These can be negated (i.e. NOT tableExists), ANDed together, etc... So it's possible add a precondition to a change that creates a table named X only if table X does NOT exist.

Comment: So your recommendation is update every changelog and put preconditions?

Comment: My recommendation is to revert to your old naming and directory. Your build process could copy these files to 'old' directory (e.g. target/classes/src/main/resources/db/changelogs/), and then everything will just continue to work.  But, if you insist on changing the directory, then adding pertinent preconditions to each pre-existing change ought to do the trick.

Comment: Looking closer at the [documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/databasechangelog.html), there is one other thing you might try : "logicalFilePath - Use to override the file name and path when creating the unique identifier of change sets. Required when moving or renaming change logs."

Answer (score 0):

When Liquibase tries to execute the script will compare the checksum to see if there's any change to be done, and you will have something like this (in the logs):

```
1 change sets check sum
          [filename]::[id]::[author]was: 7:eec7ef2a0dd6f5dc96c7a488f3943ff0 
          but is now: 7:6e98cd45fc25cf5fc182fb751b5349ff
```

So, you can update the record in the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table with something like this:

```
UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOG SET MD5SUM = '7:6e98cd45fc25cf5fc182fb751b5349ff' 
WHERE (ID = [id]) and (AUTHOR = [author]) and (FILENAME = [filename]);
```

This will prevent a new execution of the same script.

**If someone knows how Liquibase calculates the checksum, that will be awesome, right now I'm only able the get the checksum after the execution (from the logs), I tried getting the checksum from the terminal, but it doesn't match with the one from Liquibase**

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone encounters similar problem: if `liquibase` tries to execute same script again, even in one run, try fiddling with `./` or trailing `/` in changelog xml/yaml. In my case it tried to run `1.sql`, `2.sql`, `3.sql` and then `./1.sql` - which failed for obvious reasons. Removing trailing "/" from `path` helped.